# Inconsistent Datatypes: Expected DATE got NUMBER

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add a Where clause that only grabs data from that particular day (trunc(hr, 'dd')) but when I put in a sample value for HR (type: DATE WITH TIME ZONE) I receive the following error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
```

Below is some sample data for the HR Column:

```
**HR**
25-DEC-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK
30-DEC-16 06.00.00.000000000 AM US/EASTERN
```

Below is my (sample) query:

```
select *
  from value v
  where trunc(v.hr, 'dd') = 
        trunc('01-DEC-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK', 'dd')
    and v.code = 'DEFAULT';
```

Do I need to convert something? I've tried using the **TO_DATE** function but I don't think there is a date format that fits my sample data...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using TRUNC() on a string and it requires either a DATE or a TIMESTAMP.

Comment: There is no data type `DATE WITH TIMESTAMP` in Oracle. Either `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`. What did you try with `TO_DATE` - that is what you have to use! `TRUNC` on a string value does not exist.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit sorry I meant with TIME ZONE. I am going to revise my original question

Comment: @Stilgar when I queried for HR data I just copied some random Timestamp that Oracle returned to me in the results. How would I be able to stick a timestamp in the where clause?

Comment: TO_TIMESTAMP('Your string which represents timestamp','Your format string which describes your timestamp string').  As in: TO_TIMESTAMP('01-DEC-16 12.00.00.000000000 am','dd-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff9 am')

Comment: Looks like -5 gets you back to New York, so: TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('01-DEC-16 12.00.00.000000000 am -5','dd-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff9 am tzh')

Comment: @Stilgar I am still receiving the following error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: my where clause looks like this: where trunc(v.hr, 'dd') = trunc(to_timestamp_tz('18-SEP-17 01.00.00.000000000 PM US/EASTERN', 'dd-MON-YY hh.mi.ss.ff9 am tzh'), 'dd')

Comment: `TZH` means "time zone hour". However "US/EASTERN" is a time zone region, you must use `TZR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues in your WHERE condition.

`TRUNC(..., 'DD')` returns a `DATE` value, i.e. you lose all time zone information.
I would use this one

```
WHERE TRUNC(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(hr)) = TRUNC(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(TIMESTAMP '2016-12-01 12:00:00 AMERICA/NEW_YORK'))
```

NB, you can skip `DD` as it is the default.

Comment: what about when I need to round to the nearest week, month, year etc.?

Comment: Then use `TRUNC` with `'IW', 'MM', 'YYYY'` - or read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions271.htm#SQLRF52058).

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion :( , I knew that part (I can google har har, I know how to trunc/round a date to the nearest year, month , week etc.), but when I extract the date, is it as simple as doing this to round? TRUNC(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(hr), 'yyyy') ? or was there some data conversion I had to do before / after? (if that makes sense)  Seems a bit too 'easy', haha.